# Loop through all elements with class name 'blah' in jquery and use the contents of the element in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what i'm trying to do in pseudo code

```
Find all <td> Elements with Class name 'OSGridRef'
For each <td> element pass the text of that <td> element into a function called ConvertToLatLong
Update an <td> element in the same  table row that has the class name 'LatLong' with the results of the function.
```

I haven't the foggiest how to do this in regular JavaScript or in jQuery.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it. When you say 'content' I assume you mean all the text inside?

```
$(function() {
  $('tr:has(.OSGridRef)').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).find('.OSGridRef').text();
    var result = ConvertToLatLong($.trim(content));
    $(this).find('.LatLong').text(result);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, this isn't going to be pretty considering that we're working with pseudocode only, but here goes:

```
$('.OSGridRef').each(function() {
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.closest('tr').find('.LatLong').text(
        ConvertToLatLong($t.text())
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `each` to do the iteration over the elements.

```
$(function() {
    $('.OSGridRef').each( function() {
        var content = $(this).text(), // or .html() if you need the HTML
            latlong = ConvertToLatLong(content),
            $latlongholder = $(this).closest('tr').find('.LatLong');
        $latlongholder.text(latlong);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In jquery you can use [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to find all elements needed

then you can use the [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function to be able to call your "ConverttoLatLong" function.

To update a element, you need to select it (with selector as seen before) then modify it value/text/etc.

The documentation on jQuery.com could help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.OSGridRef').each(function() {
  $('.LatLong').val(ConvertToLatLong($(this).val()));
})
```

this is my first guess, i don't know if they are inputs or something else, but if you could give more details (like html) i could edit this

Comment: Thank you, they're td elements